# Can i use a variable to declare the size of an array? C

Tags: c, arrays

Can i do something like this? I think you can because it works, but i am not sure if it is 100% correct.

```
printf("Array size: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int array[n]; // I know this only works with C99
```

Comment: In C99 - yes. It's called VLA (variable-length array)... Wait, you say you already know that... What's the question then???

Comment: Important caveat: VLAs live on automatic storage (usually implemented as stack) and hence all limitations of that apply. I.e. only suitable for small-ish size and pointers to it can not be returned.

Comment: Better to use unsigned type when constructing VLA or `malloc()` storage.  `size_t n; scanf("%zu", &n); int array = calloc(n, sizeof *array);`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are strictly a C99 feature. Compilers like GCC and Clang allow them to be used in C90 (ansi and C89) mode as well as C++. For example, see the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and the [Clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html). Both compilers have caveats or extensions that may offer or restrict certain features when using VLAs. One example of a GCC specific extension is the following code which does not compile in Clang:

```
void tester (int len; char data[len][len], int len)
{
}
```

In both compilers, `-pedantic` will warn about usage in standard modes where VLAs are non-standard.

In C11, support for variable length arrays are optional. The C11 standard specifies a "feature test" macro that states whether or not the implementation supports them.

> §6.7.6.2 [...] (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that
>   implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)
>
> §6.10.8.3 _ _STDC_NO_VLA_ _ The integer constant 1, intended to
>   indicate that the implementation does not support variable length
>   arrays or variably modified types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works in C-99 and other language like C++

```
printf("Array size: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int array[n];
```

Comment: In C++ there are no VLAs, though some implementation provide them as an extension.

Comment: Except that in C++14 there's something similar called "runtime-sized arrays".